# How to push performance test logs to kibana via elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, hp-performance-center

Is there a possibility to push the analysis report taken from the Performance Center to Logstash and visualize them in Kibana? I just wanted to automate the task of checking each vuser log file and then push errors to ELK stack. How can I retrieve the files by script and automate this. I can't get any direction on this because I need to automate the task of automatically reading from each vuser_log file.

Comment: this is possible, in fact, thats what ELK stack is for. You can push logs using `beats` from any host to logstash. If your logs are file based then have a look at `filebeat`

Comment: What exactly is Performance Center? In what form are log files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Filebeat** should be your tool to get done what you mentioned.

To automatically read entries you write in a file (could be a log file) you simply need a shipper tool which can be Filebeat (It integrates well with ELK stack. Logstash can also do the same thing though but that's heavy and requires JVM )

To do this in ELK stack you need following :

1. **Filebeat** should be setup on "all" instances where your main application is running- and generating logs. 
   Filebeat is simple lightweight shipper tool that can read your logs entries and then send them to Logstash.
2. Setup one instance of **Logstash** (that's L of ELK) which will receive events from Filebeat. Logstash will send data to Elastic Search
3. Setup one instance of **Elastic Search** (that's E of ELK) where your data will be stored
4. Setup one instance of **Kibana** (that's K of ELK). Kibana is the front end tool to view and interact with Elastic search via Rest calls

Refer following link for setting up above mentioned:

https://logz.io/blog/elastic-stack-windows/